# NSPredicate with SubQuery

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I have this relationship:

```
player <—>> games <<—> quiz
```

[image]

and want to get all quiz not in a game of a player, like

```
SELECT * 
FROM ZQUIZ 
WHERE Z_PK NOT IN (SELECT ZQUIZ 
                   FROM ZGAME 
                   WHERE ZPLAYER == 1)
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Further Reference http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/2726166818/what-the-heck-is-subquery

Comment: Ugh, why can't we just write regular SQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be done with a SUBQUERY clause.  If `myPlayer` is the player in question:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(games,$g, $g.player == %@).@count == 0", myPlayer)
```

Comment: perfect, you made my day!

Comment: What is `$g` in this example?

Comment: @Dan $g is just a placeholder to represent each element of the games relationship.  You could use any name: $a, $z, whatever.

Comment: @pbasdf: Can you please help me in this query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777306/core-data-subquery-with-multiple-relationship