# core data one to many relationship, assign, fetch, predicate on NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hy,
I wish to fetch all the songs those having playlist_index = 1, suppose. I have created one to many relation and generated accessor.
and but when i am fetching songs through predicate it always give me only one song although i have added same playlist to many songs. This is how i am adding playlist to song by converting pure `NSManagedObject` to coredata generated model object.

```
-(void) addPlaylistToAudio {
 // Audio Coredata Model
   Audio *audioManagedObject = [self getAudioManagedObject:self.artist];

   PlaylistModel *playlistObj = [self.arrayPlaylist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// Playlist Coredata Model
    Playlist *playlistManagedObject = [self getPlaylistManagedObject:playlistObj];

  [audioManagedObject addPlaylist_relationObject:playlistManagedObject];
  [playlistManagedObject setAudio_relation:audioManagedObject];

   // PLEASE CHECK HERE IF I AM ADDING CORRECTLY

   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[CoreDataHandler sharedInstance] 
   managedObjectContext];
   NSError *error = nil;

   if (![context save:&error]) {
   }
   else {
   }
  }

- (Audio *)getAudioManagedObject:(Artist *)artist {

// Create Predicate to fetch managed object.
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
   predicateWithFormat:@"track_index == %ld",artist.track_index];

// Get Predicate array of managed object.
   NSArray *arrayAudioManagedObject = [[CoreDataHandler sharedInstance] 
   fetchAudioManagedObjectsWithPredicate:predicate havePredicate:TRUE];

// Managed object.
  Audio *audioManagedObject = [arrayAudioManagedObject lastObject];

  return audioManagedObject;
}


-(Playlist *)getPlaylistManagedObject:(PlaylistModel *)playlist {

// Create Predicate to fetch managed object.
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate 
predicateWithFormat:@"playlist_index == %ld",playlist.playlist_index];

// Get Predicate array of managed object.
  NSArray *arrayPlaylistManagedObject = [[CoreDataHandler sharedInstance] 
fetchPlaylistManagedObjectsWithPredicate:predicate havePredicate:TRUE];

// Managed object.
   Playlist *playlistManagedObject = [arrayPlaylistManagedObject 
lastObject];

   return playlistManagedObject;
}
```

Fetching:

```
NSPredicate *predicate_audio = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY playlist_relation.playlist_index == %ld",self.playlistInfo.playlist_index];
NSArray *arraySongsManagedObject = [[CoreDataHandler sharedInstance] fetchAudioManagedObjectsWithPredicate:predicate_audio havePredicate:TRUE];
```

[image]
 [image]

Comment: Your model shows you have a ONE to many relationship from Audio to Playlist: each Audio object can have many Playlists, but each Playlist can belong to only one Song.  Each time you add a Playlist to a different Audio object, CoreData dutifully removes it from the previous Audio object it was related to.  So your fetch will return only one Audio object.  You need to change the relationship to MANY to MANY.  (Each song can be in many playlists, each play list can feature many songs).

Comment: oh.. i got it.. i understand! so double arrow  should be both side right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `ANY` will return just one result that meets your criteria, what you really need is `SUBQUERY` where you can replace your delegate with something like:

```
let predicate_audio = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(playlist_realtion, $x, $x.playlist_index == %ld).@count > 0", self.playlistInfo.playlist_index)
```

or in Objective-C

```
NSPredicate *predicate_audio = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(playlist_realtion, $x, $x.playlist_index == %ld).@count > 0", self.playlistInfo.playlist_index]
```

Note that `$x` is just a placeholder to represent each element relationship.

Links:

[NSPredicate with SubQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688892/nspredicate-with-subquery?rq=1)

http://davidchuprogramming.blogspot.com/2016/10/one-to-many-relationship-and-subquery.html

Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: still getting only one song although i have added same playlist to three songs. Am i adding it correctly . can you please look into the code i.e addPlaylistToAudio function.

Comment: Looks OK, but because they are relationships you do it only for one and it works in reverse as well...What do you mean you get one song? Are there multiple songs that should be returned or do you expect to get same song 3 times if it is in three playlists?

Comment: yes there should be multiple song, cause i assigned multiple songs to single playlist.. there is only one playlist.. but i am always getting only one overwrited song from playlist through predicate..

Comment: Well than your model is wrong! In your model it says, each playlist can have only one song and a song can have multiple playlists, you have to make the relationship to-many for both. Look at playlist_relation it is of type `NSSet<Playlist *>` now go and check `audio_relation` it will be of type `Audio *` (single audio) and not `NSSet<Audio *>` meaning that it can have many songs...

Comment: ok i got it, i will change relation many to many, but what will be then above code? in case of reverse as well??    [audioManagedObject addPlaylist_relationObject:playlistManagedObject];
  [playlistManagedObject setAudio_relation:audioManagedObject];

Comment: The above predicate will show you all songs that are part of a playlist with `playlist_index` count equal to  `self.playlistInfo.playlist_index` as you wanted...