# Core Data subquery with Multiple Relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

[image]This is the structure of my core DB tables. Wanted to create a subquery in a predicate, Below is the description of the query.

Generate all unique Submission, where SubmisisonField.value matches with an array.
This query for image on top.

For Second image which is having Employee table request is: 
Generate all ActivityFeedCard, where Employee name matches to string. Now id field in Employee is the same field which is SubmissionField.value or we can say SubmissionField.value == Employee.id. We have to search by EMployee first name, last name etc, Thank you so much. 
[image: DB Structure]

```
 let fetchCardsContext = CoreDataManager.shared.getNewBackgroundContext(name: "Fetch Cards for display BG Context")
        var predicate: NSPredicate?
        self.displayedCards.removeAll()
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(submission.submissionTemplate.submissionField.value, $v, $v IN %@).@count > 0", empArray)
        self.displayedCards = ActivityFeedCard.fetchAndSort(in: fetchCardsContext, predicate: predicate, sortOptions: nil) ?? [ActivityFeedCard]()
```

Comment: Please can you clarify "submissionField.value matches with an array".  There are many ways to interpret that: one item matching, all items matching,  etc.

Comment: So array here is of type [String]. So I want to compare its every item to SubmisisonField.value if we have a match (array.value == Submissionfield.value ) we will pick that record.

Comment: So if ANY of the submissionField.value matches ANY of the elements of the array?

Comment: We have to find all items which are matching all items in Array. i.e ["15220", 13220] If submission.value's 2 records (Let say out of 20) is matching 15220 we will pick up those two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to "generate all unique Submission".  So the fetch request should be based on the `Submission` entity.  Relative to the `Submission` entity, `submissionTemplate.submissionField.value` is a collection (because the `submissionField` relationship is to-many).  You want to include in your fetch only those `Submission` objects where the collection "matches an array".  Assuming that you mean "if the collection and the array have any values in common", then the predicate to use is:

```
NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(submissionTemplate.submissionField.value, $v, $v IN %@).@count > 0",yourArray)
```

Or in words: "the `count` of (values, `$v`, from the `submissionTemplate.submissionField.value` collection that are `IN` the array) is greater than zero".

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and giving answer to my question. I tried putting fetch on Submission it crashed. So giving more broad picture of my query. I am updating question. can you please check it once more time and suggest.

Comment: Please do mention my fetch request if i need to change it.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are using for the fetch, and the error message that you get.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes For sure, Your answer helped me alot i am updating the question and putting fetch request code here

Comment: So when i tried your query with the relationship before submissionTemplate i got what i was expecting for. Though your query helped me to figure it out, Marking your answer correct. Thanks for taking time and giving responese for my query. Thank you.

Comment: Adding one more link which help me to understand the strcuture of SubQuery. may be this one help some one else. Just sharing. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-sub-queries/